# Error while Booting using at91bootstrap on ATMEL SAMA5 Xplained Board

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot, atmel, cortex-a

I am using Atmel AT91bootstrap to boot ATMEL SAMA5d3 xplained board. At91bootstrap will basically initialize some peripherals, and then copy uboot.bin from SD-CARD to DRAM. On successful transfer of uboot.bin, It will then pass control to u-boot.

I am getting an error while at91bootstrap loads uboot.bin into DRAM.

[image]

I debugged the error and i found that SD_CMD_SEND_STATUS recieved is 0x8040027. Please provide any suggestions to solve this error.

Comment: The root problem seems to be related to the pair of `ACT8865` and `twi read` messages.  Those four messages are not normal, and should not be ignored.  Note that the ACT8865 power management chip is connected via TWI.  The problems reading the SDcard are very likely just a secondary issue.caused by the power and/or PLL issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High probability, that you have a problem with your sd card. As I can see: CMD1 is timed out error. CMD1 is 0x41 or CONDITION OPERATION. It seems MCU tries to check card's condition or switch it, but without success. Moreover it seems that no answer from yoru card at all.
1. Try to find out the type of your card, change it for some *another* card with absolute opposite features, like if you have sandisk high speed sd card, please try samsung low speed simple sd card or smth like that.
2. Check twice your hardware. I mean all signals, pcb traces, power line for on sd card, etc.
3. Of course, if you have logic analyzer to taking packages on the bus would be a little more informative.